# Firebase REST get data

Tags: javascript, firebase, express

After watching [Firebase Cloud Function Tutorial - REST API Part 1 | Diligent Dev](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iIVlRZIo2-c), I have spent several hours trying to understand how to get the entire record that was posted into firestore. Here is index.js code:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();
const app = express();
app.use(cors({origin: true}));


app.post("/", async (req, res) => {
    const user = req.body;
    await admin.firestore().collection("users").add(user);
    res.status(201).send(JSON.stringify(user));
  });
```

The JSON data I posted was:

```
{"id":123, "name":"Tony Stark", "email":"ironMan@MarvelComics.com"}
```

In this get, the id is returned but I can't seem to access the other properties that are part of the record (example name: Tony Stark)?

```
  app.get("/:id", async (req, res) => {
    const snapshot = await
    admin.firestore().collection("users").doc(req.params.id).get();
    const userId = snapshot.id;
    const userData = snapshot.data():
    constole.log(userData);
    res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify({id: userId, ...userData}));
  });
```

There must be a simple solution but console.log(userData) is not the answer! :-(

Almost forgot to say, my request from the browser is passing the user id as a query parameter, in this example localhost:5001/projectReference/user/1  and I also tried with the Cloud Firestore document id (.../user/XRAwtfj9FSubeCArvUtQ).  In each case I see in the browser the JSON string {"id":"the_value_requested"} but no userData.

Answer (score 0):

What does `console.dir(userData)` output? That should help you see what's in the returned object.

Are you confident that name and email are avtually present on the record in Firebase? It's possible your retrieval is working as expected but the data expected isn't there.

Comment: The response from the console log is undefined.  But I also tried your suggestion console.dir(userData) and got the same result, undefined.

Comment: How about `console.dir(snapshot)` ? That should show you the ID plus whatever else the object contains.

Comment: Nope, all I see is undefined!

Comment: I noticed you said "the id is returned" in your post. Does that mean `console.log(userId)` outputs `123` ?

Comment: yes, that is correct if console.log(userId) then response is 123

Comment: Something seems off here. `console.dir(snapshot)` should not be `undefined` if `console.dir(snapshot.id)` is `123`. Either `snapshot` is defined with an `id` or it is not defined... can't have it both ways. Could you please double check and report back?